# Why do autolayout constraints in Xcode cause my subview to disappear off screen?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to figure out how to use autolayout, and there seems to be a lack of info about it on the internet. I placed a view within my view controller with three buttons inside it. Before I place any constraints, the buttons show up on the preview. However, as soon as I make ANY constraints, the whole sub view completely stops showing up in the preview. I made a constraint to center vertically, and then one to place it 25 pixels from the left edge. It should know exactly where to place it, but still nothing shows up.

Any ideas on why constraints cause my buttons to not show up?

Answer (score 1):

With Autolayouts the constraints should be as clear as possible. You can try by adding size constraints as well as fix(right, top or bottom) constraints if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't use auto-layout it positions everything manually. When you enable auto-layout it switches this behaviour off so you have an unconstrained object, which is why it dissappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't have constraints on the size of the sub view, so it didn't know how to center it. I didn't think I needed that because I thought it would default to what it's already at.

Comment: You should update the question rather than adding a new answer if you have additional information.